# RestSharp requests on momentapp's restful api

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

So Im trying to set up RestSharp to use Moment Task scheduling according to the docs
http://momentapp.com/docs

here is my code.

```
public class MomentApi : ITaskScheduler
    {
        const string BaseUrl = "https://momentapp.com";    

        private RestResponse Execute(RestRequest request)
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
        request.AddParameter("apikey", "MYAPIKEYHERE", ParameterType.UrlSegment); // used on every request
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        return response;
    }

    public HttpStatusCode ScheduleTask(DateTime date, Uri url, string httpMethod, Uri callback = null)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.Resource = "jobs.json";
        request.AddParameter("job[uri]", "http://develop.myapp.com/Something");
        request.AddParameter("job[at]", "2012-06-31T18:36:21");
        request.AddParameter("job[method]", "GET");
        var response = Execute(request);
        return response.StatusCode;
    }
```

The problem is that it is always returnig HTTP 422

please help.

Comment: `422 Unprocessable Entity` - Use fiddler to see what is actually going out on the wire and make sure it looks the way you would expect.

Comment: Im no expert on http so I wouldnt be sure how to expect it to look... and fiddler is not very friendly with newbies :(

Comment: Just looked at momentapp. Not sure why you wouldn't just use Quartz.Net available http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: hmm, do you think it would work on appharbor?.. http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1427-how-to-handle-background-tasks-on-appharbor-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I ended up with.
found a sample here
http://johnsheehan.me/blog/building-nugetlatest-in-two-hours-3/

```
public HttpStatusCode ScheduleTask(DateTime date, Uri url, string httpMethod, Uri callback = null)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("jobs.json?apikey={apikey}&job[uri]={uri}&job[at]={at}&job[method]={method}", Method.POST);
            request.AddUrlSegment("uri", "http://develop.myapp.com/Something");
            request.AddUrlSegment("at", "2012-03-31T18:36:21");
            request.AddUrlSegment("method", "GET");
            var response = Execute(request);
            return response.StatusCode;
        }
```

Im not completely sure on when I should use AddParameter and when I should use AddUrlSegment
but anyways it works now

Comment: The reason I did URL segment for that example was because their API requires a POST request but instead of using POST parameters it uses URL parameters. It's a strange combo.

Comment: remember that the best way to pass a time in this service is: `request.AddUrlSegment("at", nextRun.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss Z"));`